# Haar Basic Images

Tags: image, transform, basic

Can anyone tell how to generate Basic Images of Haar transform(not Haar wavelet). I have tried a code but it is not working. here is code.

```
n=8;    
a=1/sqrt(n);

for i=1:n    
    H(1,i)=a;    
end

for k=1:n-1

    p=(log2(k));    
    q=k-2^p+1;

    t1=n/2^p;    
    sup=(q*t1);

    mid=(sup-t1/2);    
    inft=(sup-t1);

    t2=2^(p/2)*a;    
    for j=1:inft

        H(k+1,j)=0;    
    end

    for j=inft+1:mid    
        H(k+1,j)=t2;    
    end

    for j=mid+1:sup    
        H(k+1,j)=-t2;    
    end

    for j=sup+1:n    
        H(k+1,j)=0;
    end    
end

[m,n]=size(a);    
t=a';

for i=1:m    
    for j=1:n    

        if i==1    
            p(j,1)=t(j,i);

        elseif i==2    
            p(j+4,1)=t(j,i);

        elseif i==3    
            p(j+8,1)=t(j,i);

        elseif i==4    
            p(j+12,1)=t(j,i);

       elseif i==5    
            p(j+16,1)=t(j,i);

       elseif i==6    
            p(j+20,1)=t(j,i);

       elseif i==6    
            p(j+24,1)=t(j,i);

        elseif i==7    
            p(j+28,1)=t(j,i);

        elseif i==8    
            p(j+32,1)=t(j,i);

        end    
       end    
end

q=p';    
r=p*q;

c=m*n;    
h=1;

for e=1:m:c    
    for f=1:n:c    
        for o=1:m    
            for q=1:n    
                g(o,q)=r(e+o-1,f+q-1);    
            end    
        end

        s=mat2gray(g);    
        subplot(m,n,h);

        imshow(s)    
        h=h+1;    
    end    
end
```

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: You should probably also be specific about which dialect of BASIC you are using.